# Creating loop create new dataframes and csv files based on variable in column

Tags: loops

I would like to create dataframes based on the variables a column of my dataset. I would also like these dataframes to be exported as csv files bearing that variable's name.

For a data set called "data", and the column that I want to sort by named "Item", this is what I have so far:

```
for (i in data$Item){
  filename <- paste(i, ".csv", sep="")
  write.table(
    (subset(data,data$Item=="[i]")) filename, col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,sep="\t",quote=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up using and it works:

```
for (i in unique(finaldata$Item)){
  filename <- paste(i, ".csv", sep="")
  write.csv(subset(finaldata, finaldata$Item==i), filename, row.names=F, 
col.names=T)
}
```